# Java program creates new file instead of writing to existing one

Tags: java, eclipse, file, file-writing

I am building a web app with Eclipse (Dynamic Web Project template). I want to write some data to an existing file in the project structure. The exact location of the file is: `src/main/java/file.txt`.

When the user submits a form, I want his data to be written in this file. The class in which the writing method is found looks like so:

```
public class FileManager {
    private Path file;
    
    public FileManager(String file) {
        this.file = Paths.get(file);
    }
    
    public synchronized void writeToFile(String name, String age) throws IOException {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(this.file.toString(), true);
        
        String concatinatedData = name + ", " + age;
        
        writer.write(concatinatedData);
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

The class (servlet) from which the method is called looks like so:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
        
        FileManager fileManager = new FileManager("file.txt");
        
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String age = req.getParameter("age");
        
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        out.println("<h1>Submitted successfully!</h1>");

        fileManager.writeToFile(name, age); 
    }
}
```

When this is run, the file `file.txt` appears inside my Eclipse folder, as in where I installed Eclipse. The content is written to it. But, the file found in `src/main/java` does not change at all.

Is there something wrong with how I use the writer methods or with how I placed the file inside `src/main/java`?

Comment: If you don't specify a path for the file it is in the current working directory which is unlikely to be src/main. Look at the Run Configuration for the program to see the setting for the working directory.

Comment: How would your java program know to use "/root/directory/src/main/java/file.txt" instead of any other name "file.txt"? Your code only specifies "file.txt" so it will be relative to where your program is running. You need to find a way to tell your program the complete location of the file.

Comment: Having said that, an app writing into the `src` tree is a bad idea.  And putting stuff that is not Java source code into the `src/main/java` tree is ... an even worse. What happens if you put your Java source code into version control?  What about when you deploy your app on a production server?